# Check if number can be divided by 16

Tags: bit-shift, modulo

How can i check if a 32 bit integer is a multiply of 16 only using bit operators?
I know that the theory is to use bitshift to right by 4 could anyone explain why is following expression true?

```
boolean b = 16 >> 4 == 17 >> 4;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x & 0x0F` is going to be `0` for numbers dividable by 16 (`0x10`)

```
bool div16 = (x & 0x0F) == 0;
```

If you want to check this with bit shifts: first shift out the four bits, then shift back in zeros

```
bool div16 = x == (x >> 4) << 4;
```